# Bootstrap modal that won't go away until email is entered

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Does anyone know how I can have a modal popup right away and not go away until the user enters their email?

Comment: A little bit more context would't hurt.

Comment: I'm not sure what more you'd need. I just want the modal to show up when the page loads and them not be able to close it until they've given me their email address.

Comment: You need to provide some code. It's a basic requirement at SO. Show us how you open your modal, what the form looks like, and what you've attempted to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that by tweaking the javascript options.

```
 $("#myModal").modal(
 {  backdrop: "static",
    keyboard: "false"
 });
```

This essentially sets the clicking backdrop and esc keys to false. The user now needs to press the submit button. You can perform validation to show the button only if the entered email i valid.
Although note that this is purely front end. Users can bypass this.

Here is a code pen depicting the same

http://codepen.io/BoyWithSilverWings/pen/VmQYPy

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: How does the submit button close a modal?

Comment: The `data-dismiss` attribute on the button. you can also use `$("#myModal").modal("hide");` if you prefer it that way.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help.